# Status shows Network but does not connect

Tags: networking

Ubuntu 22.01
10+ year old Gateway desktop. No support from Gateway. Not buying Gateway again.

Wired and built in WiFi network access both worked fine. Now whenever I try to use the network, I get a no connection message. Status bar still shows connection with the network connection showing a "?". It seems like an internal OS sotware problem. Tried USB wifi adapter, still doesn't work. Kind of hard to do things without a network connection.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.